# VBA How to do a recurring cycle

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that generates stickers, I wrote it this way below, so for 15 stickers. Can it be done with a loop for easier code writing because I have to do it up to 100 stickers? I have currently written it for 15 stickers and it works by changing the cell names manually because they are different.
Thank you

Code is:

```
Sheets("Helper").Range("A1:Z50").Clear
Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A8:C100").Clear

    If Sheets("Helper").Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A3:C7").Copy
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A8").Value = Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A3") + 1
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Select
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B8").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 2
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 4     
        Sheets("Helper").Range("A1").Copy
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B9") = Sheets("Helper").Range("B2")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B10") = Sheets("Helper").Range("J2")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B11") = Sheets("Helper").Range("K2")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("C9").Formula = "=IF(Helper!R[-7]="""",""SPARE"",""SS ""&Helper!R[-7]&""#""&Helper!R[-7]C[1])"
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("C10") = Sheets("Sample Recording Form").Range("F5")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("C12").Formula = "S/N: " & Sheets("Helper").Range("I2")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$3:$C$12"        
    End If    

    If Sheets("Helper").Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A3:C7").Copy
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A13").Value = Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("A8") + 1
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Select
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B13").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 2
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 4     
        Sheets("Helper").Range("A2").Copy
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B14") = Sheets("Helper").Range("B3")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B15") = Sheets("Helper").Range("J3")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("B16") = Sheets("Helper").Range("K3")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("C14").Formula = "=IF(Helper!R[-11]="""",""SPARE"",""SS ""&Helper!R[-11]&""#""&Helper!R[-11]C[1])"
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("C15") = Sheets("Sample Recording Form").Range("F5")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").Range("C17").Formula = "S/N: " & Sheets("Helper").Range("I3")
        Sheets("DUT Sticker").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$3:$C$17"        
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: `it works by changing the cell names manually because they are different` - are they? Seems to me like all you did is adding 5 to the row numbers.

Comment: If your code starts with `Sheets("Helper").Range("A1:Z50").Clear`, how to have `If Sheets("Helper").Range("A1").Value <> "" Then` `True`, to continue the code?

Comment: If you will not help us to understand what you are doing, we cannot help you, even if we want it...

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to access another cell:

```
i = 15
Cell_A15_Value = Range("A" & i).Value
```

```
Cell_A15_Value = Range("A1").OffSet(14,0).Value
```

(Obviously, as you start by row 1, you need to add 14 to get to cell A15.

Comment: Okay, but I have to manually change the names of each cell for each row. This is just for cell A1 you write and I to make a loop for everyone, would you will it help a little more. Thank you

Comment: You can make a loop for the variable `i` and use `Range("...").Offset(15*i,0)`, for all cells you are referring to.

Comment: @Misho Why don't you answer the clarifications questions (in comments)? Do you really need help? I wanted to prepare a piece of code, but how to do it if `Sheets("Helper").Range("A1").Value` will never be `<> ""` if you clear the range in the code first line? Is it something I missed?

Comment: FaneDuru: Yes, first deletes the previous data to add the new ones

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It is not tested, of course. I only tried following your code logic, adapting it to avoid selections and working faster. I would suggest you to try it line by line (pressing F8) and see what it does. I shouldn't be impossible to miss something in terms of variables incrementation:

```
Sub MakeStickers()
   Dim shH As Worksheet, shD As Worksheet, lastRH As Long, i As Long, k As Long, J As Long, M As Long
   Dim sh As Shape, constVal
   
   constVal = Sheets("Sample Recording Form").Range("F5").value
   k = 8: J = 3: M = 2
   Set shH = Sheets("Helper")
   lastRH = shH.Range("A" & shH.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   Set shD = Sheets("DUT Sticker")
    shD.Range("A8:C100").Clear
   'Sheets("Helper").Range("A1:Z50").Clear 'clearing this sheet, the iteration will never find a range in A:A column <> ""
  
   For i = 1 To lastRH
     If shH.Range("A" & i).value <> "" Then
         shD.Range("A3:C7").Copy shD.Range("A" & k)
         shD.Range("A" & k).value = shD.Range("A" & J) + 1
             shD.Shapes("Picture 3").Copy: shD.Paste
             Set sh = shD.Shapes(shD.Shapes.count)
             sh.top = shD.Range("B" & k).top
             sh.left = shD.Range("B" & k).left
         shD.Range("B" & k).value = shH.Range("A" & i).value
         shD.Range("B" & k + 1).value = Sheets("Helper").Range("B" & M).value
         shD.Range("B" & k + 2).value = Sheets("Helper").Range("J" & M).value
         shD.Range("B" & k + 3).value = Sheets("Helper").Range("K" & M)
         shD.Range("C" & k + 1).Formula = "=IF(Helper!R[-" & k - 1 & "]="""",""SPARE"",""SS ""&Helper!R[-" & k - 1 & "]&""#""&Helper!R[-" & k - 1 & "]C[1])"
         shD.Range("C" & k + 2).value = constVal
         shD.Range("C" & k + 4).value = "S/N: " & Sheets("Helper").Range("I" & M).value
         Sheets("DUT Sticker").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$3:$C$" & k + 4
         'reset variables:
         k = k + 5: M = M + 1: J = J + 5
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

If not confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? I will try adapting the above code according to its behavior on the real workbook...

Comment: Thank you, I will try and then I will tell you if it works

Comment: FaneDuru: I ran the code, but it only generated a sticker for me once. I need as many times as values have in the Helper sheet to generate many stickers.

Comment: @Misho it should iterate between all values in column A:A of "Helper" sheet. Are there many values? I asked you if is possible the share the workbook in discussion and I will show you how to use the code. Or, having a possibility to test it, I will adapt the code in a way to work on your workbook.

Comment: FaneDuru: In general, not much for the audience, if you have the opportunity in some way we can make an online connection and I can share my desktop

Comment: @Misho I am a little busy now, but I have some minutes. Do you have AnyDesk installed? Or you can send the workbook on my personal mail (in my profile) and I will look at it in about an hour...

Comment: Could you send me your mail, please.

Comment: @Misho I told you, it is in my profile... Please, right click on my user, then click `Profile`. If you intend sending a mail, please let me know. Otherwise, all mails from accounts not in my address book will go in Spam...

Comment: FaneDuru: I sent you an email.

Comment: FaneDuru: Try again.

Comment: @Misho Still nothing... Try checking the account spelling, if you did  not copied it. Does the mail appear in the Sent items?

Comment: @Misho it must be a problem with your mail. You can share it on a transfer site and delete the comment with the http address after I confirm its downloading, [This](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one, easy to be used...

Comment: On me gives me that sending is ok. Would you also look at in Spam folder.

Comment: @Misho I looked there but nothing received. Please, post here the account where you sent the file. Being  in my profile, it is not so private...

Comment: @Misho Still alive?

Comment: FaneDuru: Yes, I solved the problem by writing another code in a button that generated the new code for each next sticker and I copy and paste it

Comment: @Misho Should I understand that you did  not use the above code and used a different one?  If a button event or something else, not so important...